# Iphone 5 and Ipads sharing photos

Tags: photos, sharing

We have an Iphone 5 and 2 Ipads - the photo stream is currently set so that all photos taken on any of the three devices are all in one place.  This is now becoming annoying as I don't want to see all of the photos my daughter or my son take, and vice versa with mine.  How can we create an area where we have three separate photo streams, but have access to them all automatically?  If I want to find one of my photos I have to wade through all the stuff they might have taken.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While not automatic, you could setup separate iCloud accounts for each of you (but still use the same iTunes Store account so that you can access the music, movies, apps, etc. you have purchased) and then share a Photo Stream with each so that you can choose what you are sharing with each other.

That would be using Photo Stream. I'm not sure if there are better ways of doing it with some other apps.